# What is the matlab command for docking the figure inside the editor

Tags: matlab, plot

I know it is possible to dock a plot inside the matlab editor instead of constantly getting a pop-up window when plotting a function. However, I am struggling with finding the correct command.

Comment: Do you mean to have the figure docked in the command window? If so, try `set(gcf, 'Windowstyle', 'docked')` for an already existing figure; or create the figure with `figure('Windowstyle', 'docked')`

Comment: yes, thats it. Thank you!

Comment: Great! I posted it an answer, so that you can accept it if you will. Also, consider rephrasing your question to better reflect what is being asked (docking the figure), for the benefit of future readers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the figure **docked** in the command window, you can use any of these:

- `set(gcf, 'Windowstyle', 'docked')` to apply the setting to the **current** figure;
- `set(f, 'Windowstyle', 'docked')` to apply it to a figure with **handle** `f`;
- `figure('Windowstyle', 'docked')` to **create** a figure with this setting.